# Distribution of charges radiated by a sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Consider a small sphere, initially electrically neutral, of radius $a$, which emits $n$ charges $q$ of mass $m$ per unit time isotropically from its surface at a radial velocity of constant norm $v$.

We would like to determine the spatial distribution of charges and currents at time $t$.

---

This is not a homeowork problem, it is from a book of original exercices in electromagnetism which are supposed to be challenging.

I seem to have understood the basic dynamics of the problem, but I ran into some problems in the mathematical resolution.

I present my understanding below.

---

**Qualitative Analysis:**

- The charge density and current density will be spherically symmetric.
- The magnetic field produced by a spherically symmetric current density is zero (classic)
- without loss of generality we may assume that $q>0$. ***Assuming the mechanism by which the charges are radiated respects the conservation of charge***, the radiating sphere will develop an increasing negative charge
- any electric field generated by the charge distribution will be directed radially and will be spherically symmetric.
- At any point in time $t$, we can draw a ball of some minimal radius $R(t)>a$ enclosing all of the charges. At a distance $r>R(t)$, the E field will be zero by Gauss's law (since the charge enclosed is zero). For $a<r<R(t)$, the charge enclosed will necessarily be negative, thus the E field will be directed towards the origin, meaning charges will feel a force pulling them back towards the origin. So we might be end up with some periodic motion...
- Note that ***if we don't assume that the radiation mechanism conserves charge*** (e.g the charges are being somehow injected from the exterior into the sphere and then radiated away), we could end up with a potentially simpler problem, because enclosed charge in any Gaussian sphere of radius $r>a$ will always be positive, and thus the electric field will be directed away from origin, tending to accelerate the charges away from the origin.
- the acceleration of the charges in turn affects the charge distribution, so there will be some differential equation to solve

**Quantitative Analysis:**

Let $Q(r)$ be the charge contained within a sphere centered at the origin of radius $r$ (note that $Q(r)$ is time dependent).

Gauss's law gives: $E(r)=Q(r)/(4 \pi \epsilon_0r^2)$

Hence the acceleration on a charge $q$ is $a(r)=qQ(r)/(4 \pi \epsilon_0 mr^2)$.

By conservation of charge we also have that the charge density (which is spherically symmetric) is given by $j(r)=-\partial Q(r)/\partial t$. We also have that $j(r)=v(r)\rho(r)$ where $v$ is the signed speed of a charge at a distance $r$.

Finally by defintion $\rho(r)=\frac{dQ(r)}{dr}\frac{1}{4\pi r^2}$.

---

In principle the above equations should be enough to solve for $Q(r)$ and thus $j(r)$. But I got some complicated partial differential equation involving second derivatives of $Q(r)$ with respect to $r$ and $t$, which didn't lead me very far. Also I'm not sure whether to assume the radiation mechanism conserves charge or not.

Comment: Perhaps a simplifying assumption in these type of questions would be to assume a long time has passed and we are looking for the dynamic equilibrium solution; so the amount of charges leaving the sphere would be equal to what returns. The way you phrased the question, this is not what we are looking for, but this approach still gives you the solution for large $t$.

Comment: Also, $j(r) $ is not necessarily equal to $v(r)\rho(r)$, as there might be particles with different velocities at the same radius $r$. $j(r)$ should be the sum over all of these terms.

Comment: @Ali: depeding on whether the radiation mechanism repsects charge conservation, there may or may not be a steady state solution. For example if charge conservation is not conserved (i.e there is positive charge being injected at the origin), then the electric field is directed radially and we always have that the charges move away from the origin.

Comment: @Ali : by definition, j(r) implies that the current density is a function of $r$ only. This is justifies by spherical symmetry. So the velocity of the charges is determined for a given radius.

Comment: Would the person voting to close mind explaining what's wrong with the question as posed?

Comment: Imagine you have both outgoing and falling particles at the same radius $r$.

Comment: Also, because we only know of processes that conserve charge, it's a decent assumption to assume the decay process in the question respects it as well; unless stated otherwise.

Comment: I voted to close. You are asking us to complete (or to comment on) a calculation for you. Site policy says such questions are *off topic*. This is not a problem-solving site, which I think you ought to know by now. If you have a conceptual question relating to the calculation, you can ask about that. The only conceptual question which I see is "Does the radiation mechanism conserve charge?" Is that what you are asking? The emitted charges do not disappear, so one answer is Yes. The charge remaining on the sphere is reduced, so another answer is No.

Comment: ... The statement that you *got some complicated partial differential equation involving second derivatives which didn't lead you very far* is not a conceptual question. It is just a failure to solve what might be an algebraically unsolvable equation.

Comment: @sammy gerbil: nonsense. One important way to gain new insight is by solving problems. Asking conceptual questions only gets you so far. And math SE seems to be perfectlfy fine with problem solving, I don't see why physics SE should be any different.